# PHP sort a decoded json file

Tags: php, json, sorting

I used `json_decode()` to decode a JSON file into `$data`. So I think now I have an array of arrays:

```
$data:
1 first= "bob", last= "smith", middle= "t", ID= "123"
2 first= "paul", last= "adams", middle= "d", ID= "38"
3 first= "jon", last= "williams", middle= "g", ID= "132"
```

I want to sort `$data` by last. I think I need to use `usort()` but can't get it to work.

Comment: Please take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: what do you have so far with usort?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$data = [
    ['first' => 'bob', 'last' => 'smith', 'middle' => 't', 'ID' => '123'],
    ['first' => 'paul', 'last' => 'adams', 'middle' => 'd', 'ID' => '38'],
    ['first' => 'jon', 'last' => 'williams', 'middle' => 'g', 'ID' => '132'],
];

usort($data, function ($string1, $string2) {
    return strcmp($string1['last'], $string2['last']);
});
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first] => paul
            [last] => adams
            [middle] => d
            [ID] => 38
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first] => bob
            [last] => smith
            [middle] => t
            [ID] => 123
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [first] => jon
            [last] => williams
            [middle] => g
            [ID] => 132
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked great! had been trying for hours.

Comment: @user1561769 please mark this question as answered